# Areas' View Tag Helper Intellisense no use in Asp.Net Core VS2017

Tags: razor

I am using asp.net core 's Areas feature in my project 
I use the newest vs2017.
It's fine to use the tag helper Intellisense in the normal default 'Views' folder,But no Intellisense in the areas' view
How to solve this issue?

Comment: I stumbled into this same issue - did you find something to resolve this issue?

Comment: FYI a bug was logged here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6266

Comment: just add this code at the top of the cshtml file:

    @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

Answer (score 2):

just add this code at the top of the cshtml file:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

or copy the _ViewImports.cshtml file to the area's view folder

Answer (score 0):

It now even works when adding it to `_ViewImports.cshtml`, so for example:

`@using AmpTagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper AmpTagHelpers.*, AmpPwaApps
@addTagHelper MaterialTagHelpers.*, AmpPwaApps`