# <form asp-action in areas. Can`t find a controller. Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have one form in a page in the main area.  Views/Home.  Code and I want that you see the screenshot.

[image]

VS make a color for this form. And it is working with controller

```
<form asp-action="LoadImg" asp-controller="Account" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="ImgPost" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Загрузить" />
```

Next, I want to make the same but in `Areas/Admin/Views/Home/Private`  and I see next

[image]

First of all, I want to know why the color in VS is different? And why when I click submit it isn't going to my controller in `Areas/Admin/Controllers/Home/Load - action`

as usual, I use in areas Razor and its working. It is example of the same page in areas `@using (Html.BeginForm("PostSave", "Home", FormMethod.Post))`

1. Why I have diferent colors in main area and admin area and how to find controller in area by this way `<form asp-action="Load" asp-controller="Home" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Thanks

Comment: Try the first answer to the similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269184/areas-view-tag-helper-intellisense-no-use-in-asp-net-core-vs2017# - it sounds like VS intellisense isn't loading your tag helpers for your MVC area so you can do this explicitly using `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` at the top of your view.

Comment: Thanks. Color in VS is working now. Need the second problem.

Comment: And the second problem is done with your advice. Answre for question and I will do it as right! Thanks man!

Comment: Each area needs its own `_ViewImports.cshtml` (with the same tag helper import as in the main one). As far as route resolution goes, you need to specify the area, most likely, even if the area is "no area" (i.e `asp-area=""`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like VS intellisense isn't loading your tag helpers for your MVC area. You can register the tag helpers explicitly in your view by adding the following line at the top:

`using @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Alternatively add a `_ViewImports.cshtml` containing this line to your area, or copy the one from your main `~/Views` folder.